# What is Payable field in Etherscan

Tags: solidity, etherscan, erc-721, payable

If I mention a function as `payable` in `solidity` then there comes an extra field in `Etherscan` for the same function if I deploy the contract in `Etherscan`. It has a placeholder with `payableAmount (ether)`.

But this particular field does not appear in `solidity` after I deploy the contract and try to run the same function.

So my question is what is the significance of this extra field in `Etherscan`?

Comment: In this field you specify the ether amount which is send to that function. If you want to send 1 ETH to a function using Etherscan UI you input this amount into the `payableAmount` input, then you click **Write**. Not 100% sure, but as I remember you need to put the send amount in **WEI**

Comment: How does this amount be specified in solitary?

Comment: In Solidity you can do something like `payable(RECEIVER_ADDRESS).call{value: ETH_WEI_VALUE, gas: GAS_LIMIT}("")` where you need to adjust the values of **RECEIVER_ADDRESS**, **ETH_WEI_VALUE**, **GAS_LIMIT**, where **GAS_LIMIT** is optional. You can read more details on [**this link**](https://solidity-by-example.org/sending-ether/). There are two more options to send ETH inside Solidity - `send` and `transfer`